# alt + shift not work

Tags: keyboard

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to change the language. It is so normal and I have worked with that for a long time. But some days some thing have happen for me. That is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> not work all times. For example I can use it on libreOffice to change the language and also on browses. But on some application it does not work. I do not know why.

For example on Taskque software, when I want to add my own task and change the language, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will help...

Open a terminal and run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/keyboard
```

(or use some other text editor)

Do following changes in the file:

```
XKBLAYOUT="de,us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

(Replace de,us with your languages)

Restart and try again.

More Info http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html#id2521334

Answer (score 10):

This bug made using emacs and IntelliJ Idea a nuisance under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I found a simple workaround.

1. You can verify how <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> are not being detected simultaneously by running

   ```
   $ xkbwatch
   ```

   Notice how the blinky lights change for `ALT` and for `SHIFT` individually but not for both at the same time.
2. The output of `setxkbmap -query`:

   ```
   rules: evdev
   model: pc105
   layout: us,us,us
   variant: ,intl,
   options: grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            THIS IS THE PROBLEM
   ```
3. We will now unset <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> toggle, so that it is not prematurely captured.

   ```
   $ setxkbmap -option -option grp_led:scroll
               ^^^^^^^
               DELIBERATELY EMPTY
   ```

   The first empty `-option` erases all options, the second one just
   carries over an option we want to keep. Additional `-option` clauses can
   preserve other preexisting options.

   You can still change to next/previous input source with whatever is configured in `Ubuntu Settings/Keyboard/Typing`. In my case it is `Super+Space` (Super=Windows key in PCs).
4. Repeat step number 2 again and notice how <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> now play together simultaneously.

I am now a happy Emacs and IntelliJ user.
This is a single command workaround.

Comment: Worked for me. Nice and easy without need to restart.

Comment: Is there any way to make this persistent? I'm only ElementaryOS 6 and I have to redo that on every restart

Comment: Back when I was using 18.04, I tried modifying Xsession. It worked, but if you have a laptop, every suspend/resume cycle it would reset to the incorrect behavior. (There likely is a hook for scripting resumes but I did not pursue that route.) 

In the end I upgraded Ubuntu and did not see this problem since 20.04.

Comment: This is a problem in Ubuntu 22.04. I used this workaround but have to do this each time I restart/plug in my keyboard. It's very annoying.