# Xubuntu 14.04: Keyboard layout switches back to default

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout

Since I upgraded to Xubuntu 14.04 I have had problems switching back and forth between my two keyboard layouts: Danish (default) and Hindi (variant). If I switch the layout to Hindi and then change application, the layout immediately switches back to Danish.

This is quite irritating when, for example, I am using the Hindi layout in LibreOffice and then have to check something in Firefox, want to change music in gmusicbrowser, or something similar. Every time I leave LibreOffice, for whatever reason, the layout switches back to Danish.

Is there a box I can tick so this does not happen? (I am using fcitx rather than Ibus, if that has any bearing on the issue.)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps this http://askubuntu.com/questions/506620/alt-shift-not-work/506694 or this http://askubuntu.com/a/113517/265974 or this will help https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272

Answer (score 0):

*"I am using the Hindi layout in LibreOffice and then have to check something in Firefox, want to change music in gmusicbrowser, or something similar. Every time I leave LibreOffice, for whatever reason, the layout switches back to Danish"*

- when you go back to Libreoffice is it not changing back to Hindi?

Check right-click on the keyboard layouts tray icon, Properties (Keyboard Layouts) - Manage Layout: Per application.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I have tried setting Manage Layout to both Per window and Per application, but neither seem to have any effect. Sometimes the keyboard layout acts as if it were set to Global, but after switching back and forth between a couple of applications it will revert to Danish.