# 18.04 ctrl+shift to change language

Tags: 18.04, input-language, shortcut-keys

Can I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for changing languages? I can't set this hotkey for changing keyboard languages.

At this moment <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> switch languages, but I can't see this hotkey in keyboard hotkeys list or in

```
gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more
```

output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 17.10 can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift)

Comment: If you do it in 20.04+ all key commands with Ctrl+Shift will stop working  It's a known bug and I looks like nobody are going to fix it.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can set such keyboard shortcut as follows:

- On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS, 21.04 and 21.10 with GNOME desktop from GNOME Tweaks.

  1. Install it

     ```
     sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
     ```
  2. Then open GNOME Tweaks (`gnome-tweaks`).
  3. Select *Keyboard & Mouse* tab
  4. Click *Additional Layout Options* button
  5. Expand *Switching to another layout*
  6. Select <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> here

  See screenshot below:

  [image: GNOME Tweaks - set <Ctrl+Shift>]

  Or simply:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \
    "['grp:ctrl_shift_toggle']"
  ```

  If you do not like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> you can disable them with

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['']"
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward  "['']"
  gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey triggers "['']"
  ```

  **Note:** you will face interference problem as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in GNOME Terminal will switch language at once with opening new tab. It is known [bug 1683383](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1683383).
- On Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and newer versions this is possible from `mate-keyboard-properties`:

  1. Open MATE Control Center
  2. Click *Keyboard*
  3. Go to *Layouts* tab
  4. Click *Options*
  5. Expand *Switching to another layout*
  6. Select <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> here

  See screenshot below:

  [image: MATE Control Center keyboard]

  Or simply:

  ```
  gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd options \
        "['grp\tgrp:ctrl_shift_toggle']"
  ```

  **Note:** here [bug 1683383](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1683383) is fixed by packages from [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys) :

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

  So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard layout switcher will work normally on MATE DE after applying patch from [ArchLinux AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xorg-server-bug865/) "for freedesktop bug 865 (need to kick hotkeys on release, not press)".

  > **Warranty disclaimer**: packages were tested in
  >
  > - 16.04 LTS with HWE (Unity, MATE, Xfce)
  > - 18.04 LTS (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)
  > - 18.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)
  > - 19.04 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce).
  > - 19.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
  > - 20.04 LTS (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
  > - 20.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
  > - 21.04 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)
  > - 21.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)

  > However other desktops may have issues even after applying the patch.
  > These packages do not fix problems for GNOME Shell (18.04 LTS, 18.10, 19.04, 19.10, 20.04 LTS, 20.10 and 21.04) and Unity (in 18.04 LTS and 18.10).

---

If you are interested you can participate in [poll and discussion on community.ubuntu.com](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876).

Comment: gnome-tweaks broke text selection via ctrl+shift+arrow :( Does another solutions allow such text selection?

Comment: You have been warned about this. Possible solution is to switch to normal DE such as MATE, Xfce, Cinnamon, KDE. See links in my answer.

Comment: Ok, i see, thx.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine :) It is really sad that you can't do that without installing a program, bad UX.

Comment: For some reason this answer does not work for me (ctrl+shift) does nothing after performing the steps but Ezze's answer with `dconf-editor` does.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh please remove your comment from here and write it below [Ezze answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088572/66509). I can't give any warranty on Ezze's solution.

Comment: Is it normal that for changing language 1 to 2, I should have use `Shift+right Alt`, and for language 2 to 1, I should have use `Shift + left Alt`?

Comment: @user3933607 if you are talking about GNOME, I can't help here. Other normal DEs should work by using simple `<Alt>+<Shift>` in cycle.

Comment: Ya, Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Gnome 3.28.2.

Comment: That of course works for changing language, but, beware that alt+shift+key combinations will not work good. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1094249 So my personal solution is stick with defaults whatever ugly they are

Comment: @MikhailBoyarsky the solution is to ignore GNOME and use any other DE instead. The packages from my PPA was tested on Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce.

Comment: I read your thread, indeed it is very huevo that gnome maintainers dont pick existing patches about shift alt or so. It is totally doable and worked forever on windows.

Comment: @N0rbert, will it work with Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @ezze, yes it should. I have created packages for 20.04 LTS (focal) in [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys?field.series_filter=focal).

Comment: Setting Ctrl-Shift in GNOME tweaks breaks all other combinations, which includes Ctrl-Shift. It is a bug.

Comment: @Dims I'm not responsive for the bugs in the GNOME Tweak and GNOME Shell. Delete GNOME Shell from the system, and simply do not use it. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509) to know how. If you plan to do real work in productive way with Ctrl+Shift enabled - add [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys) and use MATE or KDE instead.

Comment: I googled a long time on how to disable ctrl+shift combination selected during ubuntu installation, this combination led me to effect described in first comment... didn't see that gnome-tweaks also contains keyboard settings, thx

Comment: awesome :D, I has been find it for a long time.

Comment: @N0rbert, I updated a system today and your patch doesn't work anymore for me. These are updated packages I found in `/var/log/apt/history.log`: `xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1ubuntu1ppa4, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1ubuntu1ppa4, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1), python3-pil:amd64 (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.1, 7.0.0-4ubuntu0.2), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1ubuntu1ppa4, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1)`. Any chance to fix it now?

Comment: @N0rbert, this is how I downgraded affected packages to fix the issue: `sudo apt install xserver-common:amd64=2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1ubuntu1ppa4 xserver-xorg-core:amd64=2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1ubuntu1ppa4 xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64=2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1ubuntu1ppa4`

Comment: @ezze Thank you! I have uploaded new *ppa5* package version for focal. So you may want to remove your comments to keep thread clear :)

Comment: `$ gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`  finally removed Ctrl+Shift as secondary shortcut for next input source, that I somehow set earlier, and cannot unset with UI, while it was keeping to conflict with Shift+Ctrl+V in the terminal .

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 21.10. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks !

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 works fine, BUT - looks like if you are typing FAST - and for example you need to switch to EN and press "?"(Shift+/) then you will see "/", not "?", so looks like some delay after switching should pass. If do it some slowly - works fine, but it is not I searched.

Answer (score 25):

I found a partial workaround based on other answers for using Ctrl+Shift and shortcuts for GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04:

1. Install GNOME Tweaks as proposed in [N0rbert's anwser](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/63516):

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```

   then:

   - run it;
   - open "Keyboard & Mouse" tab;
   - click "Additional Layout Options" button;
   - instead of selecting `Ctrl+Shift` key combination in "Switching to another layout" of "Additional Layout Options" window simply untick all checkboxes:

   [image: Additional Layout Options]
2. Open "Settings" application from "Show applications" menu at the left bottom corner. Alternatively run a command in terminal:

   ```
   gnome-control-center
   ```

   then

   - go to "Devices" > "Keyboard" tab;
   - scroll to "Typing" group;
   - set shortcuts for "Switch to next input source" and "Switch to previous input source" (an order of keys **DOES MATTER!!!**):

   [image: Keyboard settings]

   If setting `Ctrl+Shift` or `Shift+Ctrl` shortcuts is impossible using this dialog (as it was in my case), then you can change these parameters in an alternative way:

   - install `dconf-editor`:

     ```
     sudo apt install dconf-editor
     ```
   - run it from terminal:

     ```
     dconf-editor
     ```
   - go to `org` > `gnome` > `desktop` > `wm` > `keybindings`;
   - select `switch-input-source` or `switch-input-source-backward`;
   - switch off "Use default value" and input "Custom Value": `<Control>Shift_L` for changing layout with `Ctrl+Shift` or `<Shift>Control_L` — for changing layout with `Shift+Ctrl`:

   [image: dconf-editor]

   Another way is to use `gsettings set` console command as [proposed here](https://askubuntu.com/a/986629/63516):

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings \
   switch-input-source "['<Control>Shift_L']"
   ```

A limitation of this solution is that an order of keys pressed is important. If you set `Ctrl+Shift` to change keyboard layout then it will work only when you press `Ctrl` key first, and then `Shift` key. Pressing `Shift` key first and `Ctrl` after will not work in this case. But this fact allows to use shortcuts containing `Shift` and `Ctrl` keys combination in different applications , for example:

- `Shift+Ctrl+T` to open new tab in Terminal;
- `Shift+Ctrl+E` to export image in Gimp;
- `Shift+Ctrl+F` to open search dialog in WebStorm/PhpStorm.

Comment: Thanks for the note about Shift and Ctrl ordering

Comment: Great solution, works better than gnome-tweeks (check my comment below if you interesting why). Do we have any chance somehow to improve this behavior to fix this issue with ctrl+shift+anything (shift+ctrl+ - works fine) by... somehow to set for example event type - change when not pressing, but when already pressed. If someone will find solution, please notify :)

Comment: On my Ubuntu 23.04 the solution works partially: (1) the Shift key must be pressed twice to actually change the layout; (2) there are still some clashes with other hotkeys based on Ctrl+Shift combination.