# Can't install language

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, language-support

Tried to add language through the normal interface but it doesnt work. When I"m swiching to it, it still writes in English.

Found this way to do it

```
aptitude -y install check-language-support -l ru
```

but it throws errors. How should I downgrade installed packages?

```
root@user:/home/user# aptitude -y install check-language-support -l ru
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      gnome-getting-started-docs-ru{b} gnome-user-docs-ru{b} 
    0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
    Need to get 11,1 MB of archives. After unpacking 14,9 MB will be used.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     gnome-user-docs-ru : Depends: gnome-user-docs (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu1) but 3.28.2+git20180715-0ubuntu0.1 is installed
     gnome-getting-started-docs-ru : Depends: gnome-getting-started-docs (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu1) but 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.1 is installed
    The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

         Keep the following packages at their current version:
    1)     gnome-getting-started-docs-ru [Not Installed]      
    2)     gnome-user-docs-ru [Not Installed]              

No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Tried to install those packages with targeted versions, they are not installing

```
apt-get install gnome-getting-started-docs-ru=3.28.1-0ubuntu1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your current method

For me it is clear that you are trying to pass output of the `check-language-support -l ru` command to `aptitude`, but doing this wrong.

The correct way is:

```
sudo aptitude -y install $(check-language-support -l ru)
```

Note `$(...)` above - it executes the command and then passes the output as the argument to the `aptitude`.

## Fixing problems with your current method

You can fix your package errors with the following

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install -f
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

## Installing languages in GUI way

I recommend to install languages in GUI-way:

1. Open GNOME Control Center (for example from right corner of the screen):

   [image: Open GNOME Control Center]
2. Go to *Region and Language*

   [image: GNOME Control Center language]
3. Click on *Manage Installed Languages*
4. Confirm installation of non-installed components:

   [image: language support]

   and wait it to finish.
5. Click on *Install / Remove Languages*, then scroll list to Russian and check it:

   [image: Selecting Russian]

   and click *Apply*. Wait it to finish.
6. Scroll *Language for menus and windows* list to *русский*, drag it and drop to the first line.
7. Close *Language Support* window and log-out.
8. Log-in again.
9. Apply folder renames

   [image: folder rename]

   by clicking *Обновить имена*.
10. Enjoy!

---

If you need to add Russian keyboard layout - do the following:

1. Open GNOME Control Center
2. Go to *Region and Language*
3. In the *Input Sources* click add button ([image: add layout])
4. Click on *More* ([image: More]) and search for Russian:

   [image: adding Russian]

   then click *Add*.
5. Enjoy!

Note: default keyboard layout switcher is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, you may chose other combinations from GNOME Tweak Tool (with [some limitations on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/66509)).

Comment: It worked with the same result as in big commment above. The thing is I don't understand what should I do and in what order.

Comment: I edited my answer and added GUI method. Tested it in GNOME Shell session. Works as expected.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do at the first place. At step 4 it throws "could not install full language support", "Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot  be resolved The following packages have unmet dependencies" and points to the packages from the first post.

Answer (score 1):

To conclude my question. I managed to install required packages only with Synaptic package manager at the second or third try. Then it installed full language support and after relog it started typing in Russian.

Comment: Updated my answer about keyboard layout. For me it looks complete. If it looks complete for you too, then you can accept the answer.