# OS keyboard shortcuts working on pressing keyboard

Tags: gnome, 18.04

is there any way to change this behavior to working on releasing keyboard? i am using ubuntu 18.04 with gnome 3, and if i bind switching layout to alt + shift i am not able to use some shortcuts which contains alt + shift in other apps (intelij idea for example), or it is not possible to change this behavior?

Comment: 1. In GNOME it is impossible (you can kindly thank them for it as they move desktop to new era of computing). 2. On other desktops such as MATE it is possible with my PPA (see end of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language/1029605#1029605)).