# Keyboard layout switch issue in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

First of all for some reason I have two different "switch keyboard layout" hotkeys: one which I set in `Settings->Devices->Keyboard` and the second one(Left ctrl + Left shift) is produced by `keyboard-configuration` package.

Calling `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and removing hotkey binding solves the issue just until the reboot/sleep mode.

Having tried to remove `keyboard-configuration` I got the following output:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
console-setup console-setup-linux kbd keyboard-configuration nvidia-384 nvidia-driver-390 ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal xorg xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

It does not look like this package should be removed. So why there are two different sources of layout switch bindings and how can I remove one?

Thanks!

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/543324

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` you probably need to remove it from the desktop settings too. Try this command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

After that the removal of the extra shortcut should survive a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Two moments here:

1. You should not remove `keyboard-configuration` package. It is used for console (dumb terminal) sessions.
2. To save configuration produced by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` you need to update initial RAM-drive for kernels with

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
   ```

   and then reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however it does not help with preserving the changes.

Comment: It is strange. Then please add output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard` and `ls -al /etc/default/keyboard` to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help again! The problem is solved with another answer.

Comment: @N0rbert: No, it's not strange. Running the command you suggested is equivalent with rebooting in this respect. The thing is that dconf imports XKB options set system wide, and deleting such options system wide does not 'unimport' them. You need to do that manually.