# Disabling alt+shift to switch keyboard layouts in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

A while after installing ubuntu 18.04 I was prompted to select a keyboard shortcut for switching between keyboard layouts.

I choose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
The results are really annoying as they render any keyboard shortcut that uses these two keys unusable (such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to return to previous app).

I am not sure what is the program that controls this keyboard shortcut, as the one shown in gnome settings is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Is there anyway to find the responsible program?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073290/keyboard-layout-switch-issue-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: For the roots of the problem see https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/66509 and its links. In GNOME sHell we can't heel this interference.

Comment: For me worked _gnome-tweaks_ very well. And you also can configure other settings there. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/723091

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command will let you reconfigure your keyboard setting:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Comment: This alone didn't work for me, I had to also enter `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` command after the above command; as is stated here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1073524/25831