# How to install Xorg 1.18.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: unity, xorg, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

After migrating from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I faced [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865) old and annoying Xorg bug. It's impossible to use Ctrl+Shift hotkeys in Unity if Ctrl+Shift is configured to change keyboard layout. This issue is also mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/63516).

A bugfix ported from ArchLinux is [proposed](https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

but it doesn't work for Unity.

Ubuntu 18.04 is shipped with Xorg 1.19.6 while Ubuntu 16.04 - with Xorg 1.18.4 (and hotkeys were working with it in Unity). My hope was to find 1.18.4 version for `bionic` in [xorg-edgers](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers) but seems it's only available for `xenial`.

My question: how can I [downgrade Xorg](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876/34?u=solarpatrol) to 1.18.4 on Ubuntu 18.4? Should I start to [dig into sources](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/) to build it manually or is there an easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but even as being an author of this PPA I do not have a solution.
Downgrading Xorg and patching it may end with difficult long deep dependency resolution.
I tried to install Xenial HWE packages from my PPA on Bionic with no luck.
So there is something wrong inside Unity or GNOME sHell.

You can read my complete opinion on Ubuntu Community ([first](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876/28?u=norbert) and [second](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876/32?u=norbert)). I cite latter here:

> **The universal remediation to fix current bug - do not use both GNOME sHell and *beloved* Unity**
>
> and purge them with commands below:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop \
> ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-unity-desktop unity-session
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> ```
>
> **but use Cinnamon, KDE, MATE (my favorite) or Xfce instead with packages from my [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys):**
>
> ```
> #Choose your favorite desktop 
> #sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop
> #sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop 
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
> #sudo apt-get instal xubuntu-desktop 
>
> #Add my PPA
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>
> #Reboot and enjoy
> sudo reboot
> ```
>
> Optionally pin (lock/hold) related packages to prevent their upgrade with:
>
> ```
> cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-xorg-hotkeys
> Package: *
> Pin: release o=LP-PPA-nrbrtx-xorg-hotkeys
> Pin-Priority: 1337
> EOF
> ```
>
> If you are not satisfied with obtained results - write a letter to Mark Shuttleworth / Xorg / GNOME / all bug-trackers / all IRCs / all LoCos / all treads of Ubuntu-Forums / Bill Gates about your problem and then execute:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
> sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-xorg-hotkeys
> ```

If you would like to complete with installation of MATE DE you can use Mutiny panel layout to avoid some headache :)

[image: Mutiny on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

The last option - you can try to write PM to the [user, suggested to downgrade Xorg to give you complete working instruction](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876/34?u=norbert).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your efforts, I've seen those community thread and read all your messages there. Using another DE is a way to go but I love Unity very much and prefer to stay with it. Seems that I found [a partial workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088572/63516) for GNOME but not for Unity yet...