# Neither Ctrl+Alt+Shift keyboard shortcuts work if Alt+Shift is bound to keyboard layout switch

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweak-tool

On Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME triple shortcut combinations (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>) are always treated like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>, so <kbd>Alt</kbd> is skipped. However, all double combinations (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+) are processed properly in all windows.

This happens if the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination is bound to switch keyboard layout (using `gnome-tweaks`, as described here [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language/1029605#1029605))

Examples from Intellij IDEA:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>: expected *Project Structure*, but nothing happens (not sure what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> makes by default)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: expected *Resolve conflicts*, actually: *Replace in Path* is called

**Note**:

- opposite to the issue described in [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language/) and [bug 1683383](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1683383) this trouble appears as *wrong shortcut is used (`Alt` key is ignored)* rather than *unexpected layout switching*
- The problem happens in any window, not only Intellij IDEA
- The problem happens with **any** key, which includes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+

So, is it a bug that should be reported to Ubuntu / GNOME / Tweaks developers? Or am I misusing something?

Comment: The problem is very popular and painful, it will not be fixed in Unity and GNOME sHell. Consider to add my PPA `ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys` from [my answer (already mentioned in your question)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/66509) and switch to normal desktop such as Cinnamon, KDE, MATE (my favorite for last 5 years), Xfce. You may also consider to participate in discussion on [community.ubuntu.com](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876).

Comment: @N0rbert It seems the problem is similar and related, but not exactly the same: in the mentioned bugs (which seems to be fixed in 18.04) pointed that Ctrl+Shift is always caught as layout switch, but in my description i mean that layout is not switched, but "further" triple combinations don't work.