# Keyboard shortcuts don't distinguish tap sequence

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have tried to set up keyboard shortcuts to toggle keyboard layout:

- Next source <kbd>L-Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R-Shift</kbd>
- Previous source <kbd>R-Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L-Shift</kbd>

But Ubuntu 18 does not distinguish keyboard tap sequence. Both combinations toggle layout only to next source.

In unity settings the combination look like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ShiftL</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ShiftR</kbd>. Is there a way to set it so that the order the keys are pressed matters?

Comment: Can You explain please what You men when told about "L-Srift", "R-Srift" and what the difference between "L-Srift+R-Srift" and "R-Srift+L-Srift"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language) , but in GNOME Tweaks use *Switching to another layout* → *Both Shift together*.

Comment: How is this a dupe of that?

Comment: What desktop environment and Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: mature > When i speaking "L-Srift" and "R-Srift" I do mean the keyboard button, which each has own key-code. Difference between "L-Srift+R-Srift" and "R-Srift+L-Srift" is order of pressing the button combinations.

Comment: Zanna > I use lightdm or Gnome, which has the same behavior in reference to this problem. For compare, right behavior has "mint" linux