# Ctrl-Shift-F doesn't work in CLion in KDE

Tags: 18.04, kde, clion

Ctrl-Shift-F (find in files) doesn't work in CLion in KDE. How to fix?

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: How to know? :) It prints "Plasma" during load.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clion-quick-start-guide.html

Comment: Just curios, do you switch keyboard layouts with `<Ctrl+Shift>`?

Comment: @N0rbert yes I do; but `Ctrl-Shift` should not be regarded as part of `Ctrl-Shift-F` similarly as `Del` should not be part of `Ctrl-Alt-Del`.

Comment: @Dims then see my https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/66509 and use `ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys` to remove interference.