# Unable to change language with shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, input-language

I have ubuntu 18.04 with multiple languages, I tried to set the "switch to next source" in text entry settings but whatever I set there doesn't work when used.

I also tried to follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language) for using gnome-tweaks but that also doesn't make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

**The shortcuts I have tried are:**
Ctrl+Space
Ctrl+Shift
Shift+Alt
Ctrl+Alt

All of the above either in general form or Left form (Left shift + Left Ctrl, etc.)

**This are the methods I have tried to set them with:**

1. Clicking on the language icon on the top right of the screen (Marked as "En") -> Selecting "Text Entry Settings" -> Using the combination I want in the field named "*Switch to next source using*"
2. In the terminal running "gnome-tweaks" (I add the terminal output below) -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout -> Choosing the configuration I want

Two notes about the last approach:
a) After making changes and closing the gnome-tweaks GUI I get a message saying "Configuration changes requires restart \n Your session needs to be restarted for settings to take effect" with the options "Restart session", "Cancel" and "OK". I've tried all of the given options, restarting the computer by myself and logging out and back in. Nothing seems to work
b) The terminal output when running "gnome-tweaks" is as follows:

```
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
WARNING : Shell not running
NoneType: None
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 216, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
```

The output for "gnome-shell --version" is:

```
GNOME Shell 3.28.4
```

3. The last method I tried from the answer linked above is to simply run the following in the terminal:

   ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \ 
    "['grp:ctrl_shift_toggle']"
   ```

which had no effect

Comment: Using Ubuntu 18.04? what are the key board shortcuts you r trying to set??

Comment: Text Entry is a Unity thing, but Ubuntu 18.04 is shipped with GNOME. Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: You are referring to changing language settings with shortcuts, but you do not indicate which shortcuts you tried? Please add some more specifics on what you tried and what did not work as expected. Edit your question to add relevant information. Default keybinding is Ctrl+Space (see Settings - Keyboard shortcuts, section "Typing")