# Can't set Alt+Shift as a keyboard shortcut on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04, settings

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I wanted to change keyboard shortcut of "switch to next input resource" from <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> but it doesn't allow me to set it. later I found out some combinations can't be set either. Any solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language) - use gnome tweaks.