# Cant make ubuntu to switch language with alt-shift

Tags: 20.04, input

On my fresh ubuntu 20.04 desktop, im trying to set the language input switch using left alt-shift, but for some reason, the window bellow accepts other things then alt-shift...

Any idea?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language) - use GNOME Tweaks for Alt+Shift.