# Ubuntu 20.04 change keyboard layout by shift+ctrl (not ctrl+shift)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to configure the keyboard shortcut to change layout, but I want to change by <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (not <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>). I've read the similar question there [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language?newreg=0f1b4cb33a944e988bea5660fd769a2b) , but I could setup only combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. I need to get rid of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and left only <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Comment: I don't understand your question. They need to be pressed simultaneously, but to me it works both if I hold **Ctrl** and press **Shift** and if I hold **Shift** and press **Ctrl**.

Comment: Yes, it works for me too if I setup hotkey using gnome-tweaks. But I need to press shift + ctrl only (avoid changing layout by pressing ctrl+shift) on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @user1570891: How about explaining what you want to achieve? The question you linked to has an accepted answer with quite some information, including references to a bug report and a PPA. I would guess that your question is actually a duplicate of that other question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language) and add my PPA and remove GNOME shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next command does what is needed:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
```

The command switches the language pressing "Alt" first and then "Shift", but not vise versa. Instead of "Alt" can be "Ctrl" (<Control>) as well.