# Left CTRL + Left Shift shortcut can not be disabled for input source switching in ubuntu 20.04.2. LTS

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I updated my ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04.2 LTS couple days ago and noticed that the Ctrl+Shift+c combination that I used previously for copying from command line does not work now. Instead, when I press Ctr+Shift it changes my keyboard layout. The worst thing is that the Ctrl+Shift combination can not be disabled.

In Region&Language settings it says the combination can be changed in the keyboard settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gitX.png

But that seems to be untrue. Because even if I disable the switch input source shortcuts completely like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMipx.png

in the Region&Language settings the combinations stays: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE3Mx.png

This is devastating. Please, somebody help me! I need my Ctrl+Shift+c(v) combinations back so badly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language)

Comment: This is the other way around. I was looking for a way to disable the ctrl+shift combination.