# Ubuntu 21.10 - how to configure key combination for keyboard layout switch

Tags: keyboard-layout, wayland, 21.10

I use Ubuntu with two input languages, switching between them with Super+Space.

I have upgraded Ubuntu to 21.10, and during the installation it has asked to select another key combination, not offering Super+Space, so I chose next commonly used combination left Shift+Ctrl.

Now the problem - both combinations are active, and all existing key combinations that involve Ctrl+Shift stopped working. How do I reset it all back?

I use Ubuntu on XOrg (not Wayland). In the system settings it still shows Super+Space as the key combo. How do I bring up that window from the upgrade process to remove the Ctrl+Shift assignment? Was it Wayland keyboard settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language) . Drop GNOMEs Hell and install other normal desktop with patched Xorg from my PPA.

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-tweaks` helped, I was able to reconfigure layout switch keybindings.

Just keep in mind that there are two places where this combination is configured in Ubuntu:

- One is the standard System Settings Dialog - Keyboard - Input switching
- Another is through gnome-tweaks as described in the accepted answer to [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language). Gnome-tweaks - Keyboard & Mouse - Additional Layout Options - Switching to another layout.