# Ubuntu 21.04 input switch shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, input-language

I was upgrading from 20.10 to 21.04 and during setup some prompt popped-out asking me for keyboard shortcut for input switch, and I have choosen (Left Shift + Left Ctrl), and now I can't find it anywhere to change!

On shortcut settings, there is no such (Left Shift + Left Ctrl) shortcut, nothing left/right.

You can only see it under region settings.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language)

Comment: yes and no. My question was how to remove that shortcut, and that question was how to add some shortcut, which can now be done via shortcuts settings. Since gnome tweaks added additional shortcut during upgrade that didn't work the same way like shortcut from shortcut settings.

Answer (score 2):

Install `gnome-tweaks`, open *Tweaks* and navigate to *Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout*.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I've disabled it, now the above image is without that shortcut!