# remove a keyboard shortcut in 21.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, 21.10

To select an entire word, I use always (**ctrl+shift+left** button), but now after upgrading from 20.04 to 21.10, this shortcut does not work any more, because when I type ctrl+shift, it changes the keyboard layout.
how to remove this shortcut **(ctrl+shift)**, I don't want it to change the keyboard layout any more
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language). If you use GNOME - live with it, if you use MATE, KDE, Xfce, whatever - install [my PPA to the system](https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys) and continue to use Ctrl+Shift without interference.