# Can't change keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

My system is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Gnome version is 3.36.8.

I am going to Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts.

Some keyboard shotcuts can be changed, while some are not.eg; "Switch to next input source" (for language switching).
I press it, the pop up window says "Set Shotcut".
If I press e. g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the system allows me to do that.

However if I want to do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (which is the classic one for language switching), the system does nothing.. Neither works <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> etc.

As far as I see, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is not assigned to any other other command.
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, Settings does not currently accept those shortcuts.

But you can install `gnome-tweaks`, open Tweaks and use that mechanism for setting a shortcut for switching input language instead. Most of the shortcuts you mention are selectable there.

Comment: Yep, but I just added a terminal solution without installing additional software.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is like that.

And not sure for other restricted shortcuts.

However in particular for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> I have found a "manual" solution: [alt + shift not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506620/alt-shift-not-work)

```
sudo vim /etc/default/keyboard
```

Add or replace (if existing already) the following lines:

```
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

Restart the computer